# Deleted everything from iCloud but storage space not freed

Tags: ios, icloud

I have deleted everything from my iCloud account storage but it still has 2.4 GB storage available and I can not free all the space.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you removed it also from icloud.com ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like iCloud Drive is still on:[image]
Delete all files from it and then turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you have looked in iCloud drive that are still enabled what kind of files and stuff are stored there from your phone.

If its not easily managed in your phone you can try accessing icloud.com in a browser and go to iCloud drive, perhaps you have some files there you can delete to recover some storage.